# Are pyramids forbidden?

Tags: egypt

In this collection of sand toys, there is a mold for making pyramids. It makes them with faux grooves in imitation of Egyptian Pyramids.

May a Jew use these or would he run afoul of Leviticus 18:3?

> Like the practice of the land of Egypt, in which you dwelled, you shall not do, and like the practice of the land of Canaan, to which I am bringing you, you shall not do, and you shall not follow their statutes.

[image: Sand Toys]

Comment: The halachot learned from this are generally about opposing copying the _ways_ of the nations. Making a pyramid in sand with a toy is so far removed from the practice of burying the dead in tombs, I'd be very surprised if there was any issue with this.

Comment: "Don't do as the others do".  They breathe, they eat, they sleep...  Should I not do that?

Comment: @Rabbi Kaii That it is a toy is irrelevant. Would you tolerate a toy molech?@Maurice - Pyramids of this style are a uniquely Egyptian trait.

Answer (score 10):

> כמעשה ארץ מצרים וכמעשה ארץ כנען לא תעשו", **יכול לא יבנו בנינים ולא יטעו נטיעות כמותם**? תלמוד
> לומר "ובחוקותיהם לא תלכו" – לא אמרתי אלא בחוקים החקוקים להם ולאבותיהם ולאבות אבותיהם. ומה היו עושים? האיש נושא לאיש והאשה לאשה. האיש נושא אשה ובתה, והאשה נישאת לשנים. לכך נאמר "ובחוקותיהם לא תלכו" -ספרא אחרי מות ח,ח
>
> "As the deed of the land of Egypt and as the deed of the land of Canaan, you shall not do," **I might think they should not build or plant as they do**; it is, therefore, written (Joshua 11:15) "and in their statutes you shall not walk." I have proscribed for you only those statutes which were instituted for them and for their forefathers and for the fathers of their forefathers. What did they do? A man would wed a man, and a woman, a woman. A man would wed a woman and her daughter, and a woman would wed two — wherefore Scripture states "and in their statutes you shall not walk." ([Sifra, Acharei Mot 8:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifra%2C_Acharei_Mot%2C_Section_8.8?vhe=Venice_1545&lang=bi))

I.e. it's not the way they build their buildings, but rather their abominable practices that are proscribed.

Comment: Well that settles that, great source

Answer (score 0):

The Midrash teaches:

> If someone says to you: ‘There is wisdom among the nations,’ believe it. [If he says:] ‘There is Torah among the nations,’ do not believe it. [Echah Rabbah 2:13]

There are many other such sayings.  Take what is good and useful, throw away the rest.  As for the pyramid, there is a lot to be learned from its properties, and with how the ancient Egyptians built them.